# RxJava- A single Hot Source Observable? Good or Bad idea?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am appreciating all the complexity that RxJava can handle, everything from handling user events to large elaborate reactive algorithmic structures. However I still am struggling with the inception of the source `Observable` and where all events originate, and how to manage multiple event origins.

I know the answer to this question is probably "it depends", but is it a bad idea to consolidate source events to a single `Subject` or Hot Observable of some form?

For example, lets say I have a data-driven desktop application. I have an enumerable identifying the root-level event types.

```
public enum AppEvent { 
     TRANSACTIONS_REFRESH,
     CATEGORIES_REFRESH
}
```

Then I have an `AppEventEngine` singleton that houses a `PublishSubject`and provides a means to post events and access the `Observable<AppEvent>`.

```
public final class AppEventEngine {

    private static final AppEventEngine instance = new AppEventEngine();

    private final PublishSubject<AppEvent> eventBus = PublishSubject.create();

    public void post(AppEvent appEvent) { 
        eventBus.onNext(appEvent);
    }
    public Observable<AppEvent> getEvents(AppEvent appEvent) { 
        return eventBus.startWith(appEvent).filter(e -> e.equals(appEvent));
    }

    public static AppEventEngine get() { 
        return instance;
    }
    private AppEventEngine() {}
}
```

I can then emit the `AppEvent.CATEGORIES_REFRESH` to the `CategoryManager` and use [RxJava-JDBC](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjvq8OcvsfHAhXLD5IKHTUoBqQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdavidmoten%2Frxjava-jdbc&ei=7RPeVa-BF8ufyAS10JigCg&usg=AFQjCNH1mtQvnzzpg5ODPnIy9aZBduqa6A) to construct and emit a new `List<Category>` derived from a query.

```
public final class CategoryManager {

    private final Database db = //instantiate database;
    private final Observable<List<Category>> categories;

    private CategoryManager() { 
        categories = AppEventEngine.get().getEvents(AppEvent.CATEGORIES_REFRESH)
                .flatMap(e -> db.select("SELECT * FROM CATEGORY").get(rs -> new Category(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("DESC"))).toList()).cache(1);
    }

    public Observable<List<Category>> getCategories() { 
        return categories;
    }
}
```

Then external client classes can not only transform and subscribe that `Observable<List<Category>>` but also push the `AppEvent.CATEGORIES_REFRESH` event at any time.

```
public final class SomeClientUX { 
    //gui code 

    public void categoryRefreshButtonPressed() {
        AppEventEngine.get().post(AppEvent.CATEGORIES_REFRESH);
    }
}
```

My question is this... is following this `EventBus` pattern ([much like that in Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained)) a kosher way to write an RxJava desktop application? Or should I be avoiding the use of a `PublishSubject` and deriving the events differently (in a decentralized way)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a valid pattern and is a common use case for `PublishSubject`. One bit of advice though is to serialize emissions from `PublishSubject` if you expect events to be pushed to it from different threads (unless there is a formal happens-before relationship between the pushed events, but that is an optimisation you probably don't need). So the declaration should be:

```
private final Subject<AppEvent> eventBus =
    PublishSubject.create().toSerialized();
```

Comment: I'm curious, after serialization does it emit on a single thread? Or does it simply synchronize the 'onNext()' calls and let only one thread in at a time?

Comment: It may emit on multiple threads but a queue is held so while emitting on thread A if thread B pushes an event to the Subject then it will be added to the queue to be emitted on thread A. If nothing was in the queue when B pushed to the Subject then the emission will occur on thread B. This bit of trickery provides proper serialization of emissions without any locks being held. More non-blocking RxJava goodness!

Comment: Interesting, was kind of speculating how the thread reuse worked. So I guess in that particular case when Thread B passes the emission responsibility to Thread A, then Thread B never has to block.